# How to parallelize specific function in C++ using openMP?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to  parallelize this function using OpenMP but I do not know how.I have tried but I do not know how.
I do not know what else to say because of publishing my question.I need the fastest way for this, so that my program runs as fastest as can.

```
#include "Clip.h"
#include "Globals.h"
#include <omp.h>
struct Clipping {
int lowerValue;
int upperValue;
Clipping( int lowerValue_, int upperValue_)
    : lowerValue(lowerValue_), upperValue(upperValue_) {}

 };


RetVal clipValues(int lowerValue, int upperValue)
{

const int sizeClipVector = filter2ClipVector.size();

//parallelization of clipping without push.back and critical section, using omp (OpenMp)
for (int i = 0; i < sizeClipVector; i++) 
{
    int data = filter2ClipVector.at(i);
    if (data<lowerValue)
    {
        data = lowerValue;
    }
    else if (data>upperValue)
    {
        data = upperValue;
    }
    clip2CounterVector.push_back(data);
}
return RET_OK;
}
```

Comment: Why did you remove your initial question? This topic does not make sense any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenMP overhead for such a simple function (clipping) will make the duration of execution even longer using openMP!
This beeing said, in order to "work in parallel" on clip2CounterVector you need to allocate it first:

```
clip2CounterVector.resize(filter2ClipVector.size());
```

and use indexing [] instead of push_back.

```
clip2CounterVector[i] = data;
```

Parallelization is enabled by adding

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < sizeClipVector; i++) 
{ ...
```

Comment: I think, this will work,  it seems that I have problem to paralleize  other functions.. in the same way, but thank you! Just need to calculate it first :)